Coupling/decoupling power supplies: how?
I'm adding a hi-Z adapter to a solid-state amplifier that is powered from the mains through a transformer and regulator. The hi-Z adapter is powered by 24 volts DC, so i need an external power supply for it. However, the power and output signal on this adapter share the same ground.
My question is, how should i (de)couple the ground lines and/or 24 volts input to the adapter so that the power supplies don't interfere with each other, or risk burning the house down? So far i've tried a (relatively small) capacitor in series with the ground line, result is no output voltage. Then i tried putting a (i think 500ish ohm) resistor in parallel with the capacitor, this melted through the tape - without any input signal - and nearly started a fire.
...or is it better to just decouple the signal line (or signal ground) from the power supply?

The resistor should not have done that. Please make sure to explain the details of the devices and the connections, and verify there are no mistakes. The grounds of the two devices must be directly joined together for a device with single-ended audio output. But if you can do that depens on your power supplies and devices.

you can get isolated DC-DC boost/buck converters that don't have a common ground between Vin and Vout.

What is a "hi-Z adapter"?

Not sure what this "Hi-Z" adapter device is...Maybe point to a datasheet?  But in general if you are worried about multiple DC power supplies in the same circuit not having the same ground, then make sure the AC-to-24Vdc power supply has a floating output voltage that is not referenced to protective earth from the AC mains.  Most AC-DC switching wall supplies will have that property already. Then the +24V supply ground will be automatically reference itself to the rest of the system ground potential so no ground currents will flow between supplies.

Hi-Z Adapter could be a an adapter that accepts high impedance (Hi-Z) signals (for example from a microphone, guitar pickup or a record player) and converts them to line levels.

Thanks for your answer. So i take it any wall adapter that doesn't have a ground pin (ie. the plug is 2 prong) qualifies?
The hi-Z adapter is just a TL072 op amp based board for high impedance inputs, but the only relevant detail is that it has one ground node for both the power and the audio in/out signals. I'd have the exact same problem with any other device that is made like this, which includes most cheap and/or small audio devices.

The original question is very common situation in and electronics connection between multiple devices, which need to share a signal ground.   The solution is all the devices use floating power supplies
